# Complex function only differentiable in $y=x^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

> Find a function $F: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that is differentiable in the parabola $y=x^2$ and not differentiable in the rest of the complex plane.

Let $F(x,y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$. If $F$ was differentiable in $y=x^2$ then the Cauchy Riemann equations would hold in that set, and applying the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,x^2) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}v(x,x^2) 
 \implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}u(x,x^2) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,x^2) 
 \implies 2x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Outside the parabola we would have that the C.R. equations would not hold because they are a necessary condition for differentiability.

I don't know how to continue from here as the C.R. equations haven't thrown much light about the funtion $F$.

Comment: Can you find any function that is not differentiable at any point?

Comment: @mihaild yeah, $f(z)= \overline{z}$ is one

Comment: $f(x, y) = \frac{x^3}{3} + i \frac{y^2}{2}$ should work.

Comment: Also, do you need function that's $\mathbb C$-differentiable at $(x, x^2)$ and not differentiable everywhere else? Then you need usual Cauchy-Riemann, but on this points only, not differentianting along curve: for example, $f(z) = z$ doesn't satisfy your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer:$$f(x+yi)=-7x^3-3xy^2+6xy+\left(-y^3-9y^2+3x^2y-3x^2\right)i.\tag1$$And here's how I got this answer:

1. I wrote $y-x^2$ as $\displaystyle\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}-\left(\frac{z+\overline z}2\right)^2=\frac z{2i}-\frac{\overline z}{2i}-\frac{z^2}4-\frac{\overline z^2}4-\frac{z\overline z}2$.
2. Then I found a “primitive” of this expression with respect to $\overline z$:$$\frac{z\overline z}{2i}-\frac{\overline z^2}{4i}-\frac{z^2\overline z}4-\frac{\overline z^3}{12}-\frac{z\overline z^2}4.$$
3. Finally, I replaced $z$ with $x+yi$ in order to get $(1)$. (Actually, I've also multiplied everything by $12$, in order to get only integer coefficients.)

Try it with other sets. It always works.

As far as the Cauchy-Riemann equations are concerned, this method always gives you a function $f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. Besides, the equality $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ is basically the curve that you are interested in (in this specific case, this equality is equivalent to $24(y-x^2)=0$).

Comment: And you did this because you wanted $\partial f/\partial\bar z = 0$ exactly when $y-x^2=0.$

Comment: Indeed, that was the reason.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting approach

Comment: My thought exactly. (No, it was not invented by me.)

Answer (score 1):

If $F(x +iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ with
$$
 \begin{matrix}
u_x(x, y) = x^2 & u_y(x, y) = 0 \\
v_y(x, y) = 0 & v_y(x, y) = y
\end{matrix}
$$
then the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied exactly for the points on the parabola $y = x^2$. A simple example is
$$
 F(x +iy) = \frac{x^3}{3} + i \frac{y^2}{2} \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you come up with $F$ satisfying the conditions (especially the non differentiability outside the parabola) ?

Comment: @Yagger: I tried to find a “simple” set of conditions so that $u_x =v_y$ is satisfied only on the parabola, and $u_y = -v_x$ is always satisfied. That led to the above system with $u_x - v_y = x^2-y$ and $u_y = v_x = 0$. Then $u$ and $v$ can be determined by integration because they depend on $x$ (respect. $y$) only.